# Display a C# message onlyonce

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to make a C# application that displays a message when the program starts up, with a button that says "Don't show this message again".

When they click that button, how do I make it not display again the next time the program is ran.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I'm unsure on how to show a message with a button in it (new to c#) so help on that would be appreciated also.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could save this choice in the [user settings](http://codehill.com/2009/01/saving-user-and-application-settings-in-winforms/).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to record that setting somewhere that lives beyond the current life of the program.

You can use the Settings part of your project for this.

As for adding such a checkbox or whatever, you probably have to create a new form that looks like a message box.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store a value indicating the whether the user has clicked the box or not in an xml file, database, etc.

Assuming this is WinForms the message will be a MessageBox or a new Form.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to user settings, both [the registry](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sushmita_kumari/registrykeys102082006061720am/registrykeys1.aspx?articleid=0ce07333-c9ab-4a6a-bc5d-44ea2523e232) and [isolated storage](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/IsolatedStorage.aspx) provide valid places to store your data. One appeal of isolated storage is that you have a whole mini-file-system at your disposal, which can be convenient for very complex storage. In this specific case, however, either user settings or registry settings will provide maximum simplicity, IMO.

Comment: @Steven - I agree, no registry please.

Comment: Application settings files should always be stored in the `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` for local users and `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` for roaming users.  It is simple to manage and save an XML or PrivateProfile INI file in these locations.  _Everyone should stay out of the Registry._  It often becomes a mess because the majority of programmers do not know how to correctly use it, to clean up keys when they uninstall, etc.

Comment: Isolated storage actually is stored in the application data folder, and is very simple to manage. There is no reason to claim everyone should stay out of the registry, and to do so by claiming the majority of programmers are incompetent to do so is impolite and incorrect. Use the right tool for the right job, and use it correctly. Sometimes that tool is the registry. Often it is not. That makes it no less an option.